I noticed something called a Marqee tag, I've experimented with it, but cant find a way to put it in a container, I need it to not run off the page
so I found an element I hadn't heard of, the Marqee tag, but I cant seem to put it in a container no matter what I do to it, I've tried CSS directly in the Marqee tag to try and put it inside of a border, but the border just followed the element, and div tags either don't work, or they completely break for some reason and disappear off of the page, can anyone please help me?
directly HTML
<div> 
 <marquee style="color:lime; border: 1px solid lime; padding: 35px; font-family: 'Courier New', monospace; font-size:10px; " scrollamount=50 behavior="alternate">THIS IS A TEST HTML!</marquee>
</div>

in this one I'm trying to create a direct border around it, but the border just moves with it or just breaks
CSS
Marqee { 
  border: 1px solid lime;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 35px;
  font-size:10px;
}

in this one, I'm trying to use the padding to make a container larger than the word in the Marqee, that way it can bounce around inside of it, but that wont work either. :(

Marqee element doesn't exist in HTML. Also  marquee HTML element is obsolete and are no longer supported on browsers

The  tag is an obsolete HTML element, and it is generally not recommended to use it due to poor support in modern browsers and the lack of accessibility. Instead, you should use CSS animations to achieve a similar effect.
